# Библиотеки для работы с видео в Java

Tags: java, видео

Существуют ли какие-нибудь библиотеки (помимо JMF и Xuggle) для работы в видео файлами на Java?

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону [FMJ](http://fmj-sf.net/ffmpeg-java/getting_started.php) (не путать с JMF) и [Theora-Java](http://fmj-sf.net/theora-java/getting_started.php).

Можно посмотреть на разные байндинги к Java: [ffmpeg-java](http://fmj-sf.net/ffmpeg-java/getting_started.php), [VLCJ](http://wiki.videolan.org/Java_bindings), посмотрте на QuickTime.. раньше там был байндинг к Java, но теперь вроде как нет, но всё ещё [есть нативное API](http://developer.apple.com/quicktime/index.html)