# библиотека для обработки видео, Java

Tags: java, видео

Есть видео файл, формат может быть  AVI, HDrip, WMV, VOB, MP4. Надо из этого видео сделать определенное количество скриншотов, небольшую gif анимацию. Видео файл не должен быть поврежден.
какую библиотеку использовать?
[нашел похожий вопрос, но он от 2011 года.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/16154/%D0%91%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE-%D0%B2-java)

Comment: @LEQADA а если не "любой" а самые распостраненные?

Comment: @LEQADA исправил, перечислил возможные форматы

Comment: Я не особо разбираюсь в видео, но что-то мне кажется, что нет такого формата HDRip

Comment: @LEQADA это разрешение. Или качество картинки)

Comment: @DenShDen формат видео - HDRip O.o  HDRip - это не качество, и не разрешение. Это показ того, что фильм был сжат с BDRip'a 720p или 1080р - [читай тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3)

Comment: @Denis Извиняюсь, не так понял.

Comment: используйте JavaCV. Сам ей пользовался. Ваши задачи она решает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению, не могу писать комментарии, отвечу так:

1. попробуйте библиотеки, которые указали [тут в вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757508/is-there-any-java-multimedia-conversion-library).
2. а [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735716/how-can-i-get-a-frame-sample-jpeg-from-a-video-mov) говорится о том, что можно с помощью тех же библиотек, что и в 1-м пункте, взять картинку как кадр из видео.
3. для создания gif-изображений можете попробовать [это](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/AnimatedGifEncoder.htm) или вот [это, например](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html#getresource).